# SQL 2008 R2 Permission issues

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

SQL 2008 R2
The below is all being performed within SSMS

I have a Db that sat on a Dev server quite happily and everything ran peachy as sysadmin with sql authentication account.

This code has been migrated to a test box where a reduced permission set exists on the dbo schema, where users have been allocated read/write and execute on the schema through Windows authentication.

Here's where the fun starts, when I run certain stored proc's they show as succesful but error logging on the procedure advised that it cannot see certain tables or it does not have the appropriate permissions to do so.

Oddly though despite all the tables currently sit on the same schema, the same issue is not seen on all others tables.

If I elivate the permission to Db Owner, then the issue disappears completely.

Has anyone else come across this issue before and if so how did you get around it?

Comment: Offhand the only thing that comes to mind is to make sure you specify the schema when you designate the tables in the stored procedure.  I know if you don't then the DB has to look up the table in the schema.  What's the error message you're getting?  What's the offending code?

Comment: The schema is definately specified in the stored proc, the error number is 1088 and the message is Cannot find the object "xxxxx" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions..

Comment: Ok I found the issue, we have Truncate commands within various stored procs and the minimum permission to have permission to run this type of command is ALTER TABLE.This was tested and stored procs are now working as required.
Many Thanks for your response it actually helped me in the right direction to make this link.